# sqllogship.exe - how to get it to encrypt log file when backing up log on source server?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

SQL Server 2014 and 2016, standard edition:

How do I get sqllogship.exe to use built in sql server encryption when backing up and restoring log? (as part of minute to minute log shipping)

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this natively through the log shipping GUI or command line with logship.exe

You can roll your own "poor man's log shipping" scenario. Basically all you are doing is backing up, copying, restoring with standby or norecovery and building some alerting.

An older [post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/bassplayerdoc.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/your-poor-mans-sql-server-log-shipping-powershell-version/amp/?client=ms-android-google) but an example of what I mean.

Comment: Mike, your suggestion is a fair one. However, we need a full implementation of a "roll your own" (that can be monitored, logs what it does, is centrally configured, etc.). The SQL community is odd, imo, in that the built in log shipping is feature-skinny, and there is no "reference implementation" set of powershell scripts to go native. For other systems (mongodb, redis, etc) I can set up full mirroring in under 5 minutes with a few commands. SQL server, due to dearth of tools, is a genuine pita (always on is far too complex, the old SQL Server mirroring was close, but is deprecated/gone).

Comment: Always on is quite simple to set up truth be told. And there are lots of scripts out there rolling your own log shipping. At the end of the day it isn't overly complex. Backup, restore, monitor. Log shipping was never feature heavy out of the box but serves a good niche. Just no encrypted backup support natively unfortunately.

Comment: Mirroring deprecated yes, but gone, no. Replication can help also.